# The best possible way to retrieve data from web view

Tags: android

I was working on an app where the user is allowed to use his/her gmail account to access user-related data specifically related to latitude API , the problem is to access this data I **must** use the OAuth2.0 protocol [Check here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2), to do so I need to let the user access the account via web view to enter username and password and give permission , the protocol requires to set the redirect_uri to [either a new page or http://localhost?code=`accesscode`](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp#choosingredirecturi)  , to access this data I need that `accesscode` so I must retrieve it , the only way I did was to set the redirect_uri to `localhost` use a `WebViewClient` and override `ShouldOverrideLoad` and see if the address starts with `localhost` it extracts the access code return true and use the code , this seems totally inefficient so I want to know if there's any other possible way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you clarify the need to use a WebView? Can't you use a simple [HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html)? Also, many people already have the Google account synced on their device. You might want to investigate the AccountManager and see if you can use that instead of having the user type in credentials.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ,  The idea is that it's not enough to to just log on with your account you need to accept certain permission to allow the application to access the required data , as far as I know this must be done in a web view , I will see about the AccountManager but I think I will always need a web view to access permission

Comment: Great I found this session that covered using AccountManager to access google latitude , http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/best-practices-for-accessing-google-apis-on-android.html

Comment: I see your point. In that case, your solution doesn't seem too bad actually.

Comment: Oh! Awesome! That should be much easier on the user

Comment: Of course as you stated he will be likely to have his account synced , thanks a lot for your help